# When case is included in Array

Tags: ruby

Is this even possible with a `switch case`? I looked at the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109146/is-it-possible-for-when-to-check-the-if-the-variable-belongs-to-an-array), but it's not adaptable.

```
step = 'a'
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']

case step
when arr.include?
  puts "var is included in array"
when "other"
  puts "nothing"
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`when` clauses can accept multiple values:

```
case step
when *arr
  puts "var is included in array"
when "other"
  puts "nothing"
end
```

Comment: Thanks. How does this work? Is that a `splat` for the array or something?

Comment: @ElijahMurray: Yes, it's just a normal splat.

Answer (score 3):

This option deserves to be mentioned:

```
step = 'a'
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
case
when arr.include?(step)
  puts "arr matches"
when arr2.include?(step)
  puts "arr2 matches"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can supply a proc to a case statement:

```
case step
when ->(x){ arr.include?(x) }
  puts "var is included"
when "other"
  puts "nothing"
end
```

This works because ruby uses the `===` operator to determine equality in a case statement, and `Proc#===` executes the proc using the compared value as an argument. So:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
proc = ->(x){ arr.include?(x) }
proc === 2 #=> true
```

...although I rather like @Chuck's splat operator for this particular situation.